# How can I flip the grass mesh in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm new to Unity and I need help solving my problem. When generating grass in terrain, the grass turns 180 degrees. When changing the rotation of the model in the "transform" component, nothing happens. I also tried to change the model in blender, but the problem was also not solved.

I understand that it's about the mesh model, but I still don't understand how to fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have to seem problem with trees in terrain. I resolved this problem in blender. Did you apply all transforms in Blender after all modifications? CTL+A in object mode ad select "All transforms".

Comment: After using blender, the grass model rotated and displayed correctly in Unity, but its mesh still remained unchanged. I'll still try your method when the time comes.